# Nvidia xserver settings reset to default on every boot in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I have a nvidia quadro 600 card which has a DVI port. Since I am using a VGA monitor I have to use a DVI to VGA converter. Because of this or I dunno what exactly, I cannot select my monitor's native resolution of 1366x768 I instead have to settle for 1360x768.

Besides this even after applying the settings to use 60Hz(2) refresh rate from the Nvidia xserver settings after every reboot the settings get reset to Auto settings. This makes the display blurry and out of range. I have tried deleting the xorg config file and making Nvidia XServer settings write out a completely new xorg.conf file with the new settings. Still the problem persists.

I have dual booted the system and Windows 10 faces no such issues.

Using Nvidia Driver Version: 375.66
I have also installed cuda, does it cause such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it turns out, the issue was with the converter / adapter. When I plugged in a DVI monitor, the settings stuck and didn't reset. Used a different VGA adapter, and the settings were still there.